# How to fix double output in python

Tags: python, render, stdout

How do i fix a bug where Hello world! is printed twice?

The output:

{clear}Hello World!
{clear}{clear}Hello World!
The terminal is cleared
[Finished in 3.4s]

The code:

```py
messages = []

def render():
    os.system("cls")
    for msg in messages:
        print(msg)

def msg(message:str):
    messages.append(message)
    render()
def clear():
    messages = []
    os.system("cls")

msg("Hello world!")
time.sleep(3)
clear()
msg("The terminal is cleared")
```

Comment: It's only printed for one time on my side.

Comment: Each call to `render` prints *everything* in `messages`, and `msg` appends `"Hello world!"` to this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clear` does not clear the *global* list `messages`; it creates a new *local* variable that is assigned an empty list before going away when `clear` returns. Either use `global`

```
def clear():
    global messages
    messages = []
    os.system('cls')
```

or use the `clear` method:

```
def clear():
    messages.clear()
    os.system('cls')
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not notice at first but thanks for your answer! I also appreciate the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

in your "clear" routine you need to add "global messages".  this will allow the "messages=[]" to work on the global variable instead of the local copy.

Comment: "instead of the local copy." - this is not a copy. This is a completely different variable, which only happens to have the same name as some global variable.